# Coulomb & Electric Fields (Highschool Physics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

If an electric field is said to have a  strength of $10^{-15} N/C$, what does this mean? N is Newtons, C is coulomb - I'm not sure how they link?

So then I am asked to calculate the force on the electron and show unit, direction and number.

I know force is = QE where Q is electric charge in Coloumbs and E is electric field strength in newtons / coloumb. The electric field has force of $10^{-5}$.

So I do $(1.6 * 10^{-19}) * (10^{-5})$

and I get $1.6 * 10^{-24} N $- the correct answer is $1.6 * 10^{-14} N$ Left.

I am off by a large factor, and I don't know how the left direction was derived. I hope I formatted everything clearly here.

Comment: You mentioned voltage in the title and tags, but your question doesn't involve voltage.  Is there more detail you could provide, or is the question not about voltage?

Comment: @dolphus333 You are correct. Fixed error.

Comment: Did you intend to switch from $10^{-15}$ to $10^{-5}$? That would explain the factor of $10^{10}$ difference between your answer and the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field is usually stated as "force per mass", where mass is weight, charge or (in the old days), a magnetic mass.  So one could set

field = force / charge = Newtons per coulomb.
   field = gradient of potential = volt per metre.

In the first case, one gets a force when a test charge of q Coulombs is placed at a point in the field, then F = Eq.

The equation value F = Eq, applied to 10^-19 C * 10^-5 N/C = 10^-24 C,  if you want to get an answer of 10^-14, then you really need to get 10+5 V/m.  Typos are not unknown in texts.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. Do you know how the 'left' was derived in the original post? Ie, how do you know direction?

Comment: I have spent a lifetime picking out modal errors.  That means, you evidently have an error, and you try to guess what is the least needed mistake to produce this.  I would suggest that the negative sign here has carried through from an earlier example.  It is possible that a keying error might be made, but the field is out of range in this case.  10^5 V is quite high too, but not unknown.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, I don't know where you are getting at. I was not being sarcastic in my first comment.

Comment: The equation does not give the right answer.  Something printed is wrong.  You then poke in the equation, assuming that E is wrong or F is wrong or e is wrong.  You then look at the kinds of errors, and reduce it to something likely. You are getting the right F for the supplied values, but that answer is not what is in the answers.  So the person who made the answer sheet or the person who typeset the question sheet made an error.

Answer (score 0):

$10^{-5}\,V/m$ seems to be a very weak electrical field. Maybe there is a typo in your problem and its correct value should be $E = 10^5\,V/m$?

Comment: No typo there, it specifically states "The field has a strength of 10^-5 N/C"